# How to express if the an access tabel is empty

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to run the following code, and I got two problems as below:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("All")
Do While Not rs.EOF

Set ra = db.OpenRecordset("Archive")
Do While Not ra.EOF

if IsEmpty(ra) then    ' is this expression correct? "problem 1"

do something A

elseif ra!name <> rs!name the ' and here the program don't respect "<>" "Problem 2"

do something B

Else

End If

ra.MoveNext
Loop


rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
End Function
```

Does somebody have a suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: 1: What exactly do you want to check with `IsEmpty(ra)`? 2: Don't use field names `name`, it's a reserved word.

Comment: I wan to check if the table "Archive" is empty or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably think of something like this:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("All")
Set ra = db.OpenRecordset("Archive")
If ra.RecordCount > 0 Then    
    Do While Not (rs.EOF Or ra.EOF)
        If IsNull(ra!name.Value) Then
            ' do something A
        ElseIf ra!name.Value <> rs!name.Value Then
            ' do something B
        Else
            ' do nothing
        End If
        ra.MoveNext
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rs.Close
ra.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set ra = Nothing
```

Comment: yes but I want not just to check if "ra!name" is empty but all the table "Archive"

Comment: A field can be Null or have a value, not "empty". If you mean if no records exists, see edit.

Comment: @user3569647 "all the table"? If no records exist then `if ra.recordcount=0 then... ` would tell you if the table is empty, but also the `do while not ra.EOF` would prevent you from entering the loop if Archive is empty anyway.

Comment: ahhh, exactly that was my problem

Comment: how can I check if a row "X" contains a value "y"?

Comment: Loop the _Fields_ collection of the record (row).